# Error in form submission through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to submit a form through javascript function. But in doing so I'm getting an error on the line where I'm submitting the form. Here is the code:

"https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPWA81GSTXIG"

Im getting " Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function " error on line document.getElementById("theform").submit();

Why is this happening, i'm kind of stuck here for a while.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Did you create an element with "theform" id?

Comment: yes i did. you can see it in the code on the link mentioned. I set the id element of the form to "theform".

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your button element. If you call it the same as the method, then it gets overridden, i think. Call it "btn-submit" or just something different than submit.

Answer (score 0):

Add listener from js:

`document.getElementById("submit").onclick = validate_certificate`

Check the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sultan_arziev/hoecf52r/6/)**